# How to connect to database using ODBC DSN without ID and password in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dsn

When I configured my ODBC DSN, Why do I need to set parameters of ODBC connection string -User-ID & Password- again? using Sql Server Driver.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace ODBC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        OdbcConnection conn = new         OdbcConnection("Dsn=MyDSN;Uid=***;Pwd=****;");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "select top 1 " + comboBox4.SelectedItem + " from " + comboBox3.SelectedItem + "  ORDER BY " + comboBox4.SelectedItem + " DESC";
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            ...
        }
    ...
    }
...
}
```

Comment: First of all, please use parameterized queries. This kind of string concatenations are open for SQL Injection attacks. Also if you get your column and table names from users input, you need to use strong validation or a black list at least for them.

Comment: yes sure sir,this is demo only.problem is that when i already configured ODBC DNS than why i need again in odbc connection string.

Comment: What do you need again in ODBC connection string? please clarify me. ;).

Comment: I want make connection without user id and password.Is this possible or not?

Comment: Which one of DSN Drivers are you using?

Comment: As I know if your DSN Driver supports *trusted connections* it is possible to don't use User-ID and Password, and if not DSN files doesn't store Password ;).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: DNS or DSN - which is this question is *actually* about? I'm confused.

Comment: opppss... sorry its DSN